# is it possible to do form validation in the submit handler?

Tags: angularjs

You can do form validatin using html in angular, but if you hit the `<enter>` key in an input field, the form gets submitted with all data being undefined (disabled button is ignored).

How can I do form validation in the `ng-submit="submitForm()"` handler (where it belongs).

Edit: so everyone is telling me that `enter` triggers the submit button to submit (and since its disabled it should work) -- I don't believe this to be true, but here's my form. For me it just submits when i hit enter.

```
<form novalidate class="user" name="user" ng-show="showUserForm" ng-submit="joinChat()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter nick" required ng-model="user.nick" tabindex="1" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="10">
    <button ng-disabled="user.$invalid">Join</button>
</form>
```

Here's what `joinChat()` does:

```
    $scope.joinChat = function(){
        $scope.showPostMessage = true;
        $scope.showUserForm = false;

        socket.emit('chat:join', { nick: $scope.user.nick });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you turn off html5 validation by setting `novalidate` on your form and make sure your form has a name. This makes it easy to pass the form controller to your submit handler:

```
<form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm(myForm)"></form>
```

Then in your handler you can do what you want:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(form){
    if(form.$invalid){
       alert("FORM INVALID");
    } 
    else{
        // do whatever you want to do on form submit.
    }
};
```

If you want to do additional validation you can use the form object to access all form controls, read their values and set their valid state. The form object is a formController who's api is documented here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController

You can also access each individual control. For example if you have an input like:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="someValue" />
```

You can access it from the form object like so:

```
form.myInput;
```

You can then do anything documented in ngModelController:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

For example, you can set the input to be invalid:

```
form.myInput.$setValidity('someCustomError', false);
```

You can read the current value:

```
var currentValue = form.myInput.$viewValue;
```

etc...

Comment: This is ok, i can at least return false to stop the form from being submitted. But it doesn't answer my question of wherther i can do other validation and how i would surface those back to the form ng-invalid etc.

Comment: thanks. I also noticed I don't need to pass the form to the handler if the form has a name. It can be referenced by $scope.formName

Comment: That's true, although sometimes that won't work (if there is a directive that creates a scope in between the controller where the handler is and the form).